# How to Resolve CORB Issue using Drupal Docker Container

Tags: 8, javascript, http-request

I'm running the latest version of the Drupal docker container.
I'm trying to make a GET API call via Javascript and I'm receiving back CORB (**cross-origin-read-blocking**) errors in the Console when trying to make a get request and displaying the output in console.log.
I'm using [JSON API](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi) module to query the API.

Everything is being done on localhost.
I have Drupal running on port 4700 and just testing with a local HTML file and JS file.

In Firefox, I can see an actual response in the Network tab, but under Console I'm receiving a similar message about CORS/CORB.

How do I modify the **Access-Control-Origin-Allow** in Drupal to *

Here is the JS I'm using for my call:

```
  // Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

  // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45 ', true)

  request.onload = function() {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    <!-- var data = JSON.parse(this.response) -->

<!-- data.forEach(processed { -->
  <!-- // Log the repsonses -->
  <!-- console.log(processed.block) -->
  }

  // Send request
  request.send()
```

Comment: 'code'  // Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

  // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:4700/jsonapi/node/espot_html/fbaab7dd-09c2-4aa0-852d-4b9462074a45 ', true)

  request.onload = function() {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
 <!-- var data = JSON.parse(this.response) -->

<!-- data.forEach(processed { -->
  <!-- // Log each movie's title -->
  <!-- console.log(processed.block) -->
  }

  // Send request
  request.send()

Comment: You can change CORS support in your `services.yml` take a look here is documentation page  https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637 and also see this https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-03-31/drupal-8-cors-set-up-for-services

Comment: You use json api module so this can work for you https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637#comment-13047825